# Optimise Pymongo query time

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am running a query on mongo db and looking for a solution(s) to optimise the time taken.

my query is like `collection.find({'nameId':989080880,'Date':{'$gte':startDate}})`

what I did is as below

```
pd.DataFrame(collection.find({'nameId':989080880,'Date':{'$gte':startDate}}))
```

this query took: x ms

then i tried

```
document=[]
for doc in collection.find({'nameId':989080880,'Date':{'$gte':startDate}}):
   document.append(doc)
```

but it gave only a 15% improvement over x ms

Can not index as 'nameId' is a longinteger and indexing will require much more RAM etc.

looking forward to some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First is to optimize list using list comprehension, sth like:

```
 document=[doc for doc in collection.find({'nameId':989080880,'Date':{'$gte':startDate}})]
```

Second, If you don't need all the field in your doc, just use projection, it an object containing all the fields u need to return.
with `projection = { name: 1, address: 1}` in your find query, all your documents only return name, address field, and also _id.
For more information, you can read [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)